# Setting DataContext on DataGrid.RowStyle

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, resharper

Using the following sample R# (resharper) is not able to find the datacontext of the Row style and warns about a wrong binding (at runtime works fine). Seems like the Style is not getting the DataContext of the ItemsSource:

[image]

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="TestDatacontext.MainWindow"

    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:testDatacontext="clr-namespace:TestDatacontext"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"

    mc:Ignorable="d"

    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance testDatacontext:MainWindowVM}"  >

<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" >
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow" >
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Name}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>
</Window>
```

MainWindowVM:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace TestDatacontext
{
    class MainWindowVM
    {
        public ObservableCollection<ItemVM> Items { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

ItemVM:

```
namespace TestDatacontext
{
    class ItemVM
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are correct, ReSharper has no knowledge about how `RowStyle` will be used in this particular control (is it style per every item of `ItemsSource`? or some kind of header style and bindings will have access to `ItemsSource` object itself?), so it stops traversing tree looking for `DataContext` type on `Style` declaration.

This issue can be solved with additional annotation on `Style` declaration:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridRow" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance vms:ItemVM}">
  <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Name}" />
</Style>
```

Project will compile fine, VS designer and R# will work, but VS xaml support will produce 1 error in errors window - "Property 'DataContext' is not attachable to elements of type 'Style'". That's a bit annoying, but works. Other way is to quilify property type like this:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
  <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding (vms:ItemVM.Name)}" />
</Style>
```

But it produces VS xaml support error too :) and have slightly different behavior in runtime - this binding will work only with `Name` property of `ItemVM` type and will not work if somehow VM object will be replaced with some other object of different type with `Name` property at runtime (so binding became "strongly-typed").

We are still looking for a better way to solve this kind of problems in ReSharper 8.0 and make VS designer happy, sorry for confusing!

Comment: Thanks for clarifying but ... I cannot see where the relation 1 item of ItemsSource == 1 Row is not valid and if it is you can set the DataContext of the RowStyle to the one of each row can't you?

Comment: ReSharper do not know what semantic of `Row` is and _how_ the style will be used by control (or will it be ever used?). Just like here, R# has no idea what `ColumnHeaderStyle` is and how it relates to `ItemsSource` of containing control: https://gist.github.com/4125475

Comment: <!-- ReSharper disable Xaml.BindingWithContextNotResolved --> is what I had to use.

Comment: Any progress on this one? ;-)